# Updating an Image url in an UpdatePanel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, updatepanel, asyncfileupload

I have a **GridView** in which I have an **UpdatePanel**. I am trying to update the I**mage URL** of my **asp:image** by using AJAX **ASyncFileUpload**. I've been searching on Google for a solution for the past 2 days now.

Here is the code:

**Update panel:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlInfo" runat="server" Font-Names="Times New Roman" UpdateMode="Always" EnableViewState="true" 
                                style="display:none; background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:20px; margin:50px; border:3px solid #4B0303; color:Black; 
                                width:inherit;" 
                                >
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                <div runat="server" class="divTable" style="width:inherit;">

                                    <div runat="server" class="divRow" style="text-align:center; width:300px; float:left;">
                                        <asp:Image ID="imgUser" runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="~/silhouette.jpg"
                                             Width="100px" Height="100px" EnableViewState="true"/>
                                        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupEUpload" runat="server" 
                                            CancelControlID="btnClosePnl" OnCancelScript="HideModalPopup()"
                                            TargetControlID="imgUser" PopupControlID="pnlUploadImage" Drag="True" 
                                            BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBg" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True"  />
                                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlUploadImage" runat="server" Font-Names="Times New Roman" 
                                            style="display:none; background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:20px; 
                                            margin:50px; border:3px solid #4B0303; color:Black; width:inherit;" 
                                            >
                                                <asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload" runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="OnUpdateComplete"/>
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnClosePnl" runat="server" Text="Close"/>
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" OnClick="OnUpdateComplete" Visible="false"  />
                                        </asp:Panel></div>

//more code
</div>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="AsyncFileUpload" EventName="UploadedComplete" />
                                </Triggers>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel></div>
```

The Update Panel is part of a **ModalPopupExtender**, so is the *pnlUploadImage*. These works fine. The **GridView** works fine too.

**Background code:**

```
protected void OnUpdateComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image ImgUser = new Image();
            AsyncFileUpload asyncSender = new AsyncFileUpload();
            AsyncFileUpload asyncGv = new AsyncFileUpload();

            //finding the row of the sender
            asyncSender = (AsyncFileUpload)sender;

            foreach (GridViewRow Row in gvData.Rows)
            {
                asyncGv = (AsyncFileUpload)Row.Cells[0].FindControl("AsyncFileUpload");
                if (asyncSender.ClientID == asyncGv.ClientID)
                {
                    ImgUser = (Image)Row.Cells[0].FindControl("imgUser");
                    ImgUser.ImageUrl = asyncSender.FileName;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

The **btnUpdate** was a possible solution that ended up not working. Basically, when I click on the Image, the **AsyncFileUpload** pops in a popup format. Then I choose an image and Upload it. I trigger the Update on the **UploadComplete** which is suppose to change the Image URL.

The problem is that the image that I see (*silhouette.jpg*) stays there even after going trough **UploadComplete**. When I do a step by step, I see my that the **ImageURL** is being changed. I checked and it is the right image that is being selected in the function.

Overall, why does, even thought the ImageURL is being changed in the backcode, the image that I see on my browser does not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to create an asp:button with a method click that had a javascript postback in it. Then I created a asynchPostBack trigger in teh update panel on the button I just created. It forces a postback but it is the only way to automatically update the picture.

Comment: is there a way to invoke a postback without creating a button?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `pnlInfo.Update()` to the end of `OnUpdateComplete()`

Comment: My apologies.  I now see that you have the updatepanel set to always update anyway.  

I suspect your issue lies in having the UpdatePanel within the GridView.  It seems like gvData might not update unless you called DataBind again, but that would overwrite the updates you made.

I would recommend switching it up and putting the GridView within the UpdatePanel.